# Using a return value from an imported file to start another function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python and seemed to have confused myself. I am trying to make a game that uses different files, these have classes and functions in them and the functions return a value depending on what happens. 
For other classes to work in the master file I need the values from these separate files to be seen my the master file.

My code looks a bit like this:

This is the master file:

```
class Home(Scene):
    def enter(self):

        task45Home 
        return 'forest'
        ###Works to start forest. 
        ###Happens even when dead though.


class Forest(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        task45Forest
```

This is from task45Home:

```
action = raw_input("> ")

if action == "forest":
    print "Will you ever return?"
    return 'forest'

elif action == "look":
    print "\nYou look around the room and see several items."
    return 'forest'
```

I need these return values so that the scenes can change:

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
          'home': Home(),
          'forest': Forest(),
          'cave': Cave(),
          'passageway': Hidden_Passageway(),
          'pirates' : Pirate_Cove(),
          'death': Death()
             }


def __init__(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scene = start_scene

def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

def opening_scene(self):
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map('home')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to get the return value into the master file?

Comment: Your code is rather incomplete and can't be executed. Please do try to make it a [mcve]. Your `task45Home` code only makes sense if in a function for example, while the last code snipped is missing a `class` definition and most of the dictionary syntax.

Comment: It looks like you're writing module-level code and then trying to "call" that code by writing the name of the module, i.e. `task45Home`. That's not how it works. Modules can't return anything. You have to create functions in your modules, and call those functions.

Comment: If I call the functions from the separate files will this allow the return values to work?

Comment: @sleepy_gamer Yes. You should probably take a look at the [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) section of the python tutorial.

Comment: @Rawing Thank you for your help! I'll give it a read and try it out.